# C# asp.net show a "Saved OK" label for 2 seconds

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, hide

I'm making a "Saved OK" label visible when the content of a page has been saved, but I'l like to hide it after 2 seconds. I've tried a few examples but I can't get any to work. I thought that the javascript below should work but it doesn't (and I'm new to javascript)

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="Server">

<script type="text/javascript">
    function HideLabel() {
        var seconds = 2;
        setTimeout(function () {
            document.getElementById("<%#UxLabelSavedOk.ClientID %>").style.display = "none";
        }, seconds * 1000);
    };
</script>
```

I'm calling the javascript when the data is saved:

```
UxLabelSavedOk.Visible = true;
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "alert", "HideLabel();", true);
```

but the label doesn't disappear. Hope that you can help

Comment: Try  using <%= instead of <%# in your javascript. The version you're using is for data binding and not writing content.